# Posicionamento com ponteiros

Tags: c

Escrevi esse código para fazer `switch` entre as letras de uma string, mas nem chega a printar nada, alguém pode me explicar o por que?

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char *p, *p1, p2;
        char str[10];
        fgets (str, 10, stdin);
        p=str;
        p1=str;
        while (*p1 != '\0')
        {
                p1++;
        }
        while (p!=p1)
        {
                p2=*p;
                *p=*p1;
                *p1=p2;
                p++;
                p1--;
        }
        printf ("\n%s", str);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: seu código está muito confuso...coloque comentários no código explicando o que você está tentando fazer

Answer (score 1):

No segundo ciclo `while` a primeira troca mete `'\0'` na primeira posição da string, efectivamente ficando a string vazia.

Assumindo que o utilizador faz input de "foo".

Imediatamente antes do ciclo while a situação é:

```
| f | o | o | \0 |
  ^ p         ^ p1
```

Na execução do loop, o `'\0'` é trocado com o `'f'` e os ponteiros actualizados.

```
| \0 | o | o | f |
       ^ p ^ p1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
 {
char *p, *p1, p2;
char str[10];
fgets (str, 10, stdin);
p=str;
p1=str;
while (*p1 != '\0')
{
    p1++;
}
while (p < p1)
{
    p2=*p;
    *p=*p1;
    *p1=p2;
    p++;
    p1--;
}
printf ("\n%s", p1);
return 0;
}
```

Apenas trocas a condição dentro do segundo while, e no printf trocas str por p1 ;)

Answer (score -1):

Estás a fazer print da var `str` mas essa var não tem valor nenhum por isso estás a dar print a um whitespace.